# No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"transactions"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, tdd, testcase

I'm trying to do some basic testing of my application.

I have a controller transactions_controller.rb with a method 'create' there. Here is my routes:

```
  root GET  /                          home#index
       PUT  /transaction/:id(.:format) transactions#create
       GET  /transaction/:id(.:format) transactions#show
       GET  /types/:type(.:format)     transactions#types
       GET  /sum/:id(.:format)         transactions#sum
```

Here is the code inside transactions_controller_test.rb test method:

```
  test "should create new transaction" do 
    put :create, { amount: 7000, type: "cars", parent_id: 2 }
    assert_response(:success, message = '{ "status": "ok" }')
  end
```

And it produces the following error if I run rake test:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"transactions"}
```

Why if everything is in place? Could anybody help me?

Comment: Can you update the question with `routes.rb` code?

Answer (score 1):

Error in routes.rb

```
PUT  /transaction/:id(.:format) transactions#create
```

Should be

```
POST  /transactions(.:format) transactions#create
```

Your route is route for transactions#update (PUT request with id param). 
It should looks like:

```
resources :transactions, only: [:show, :create]
```

Comment: Thou shall not use PUT to create a resource. Its the 5th commandment :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`POST` not `PUT` to create a resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). In Rails and REST in general the `PATCH` or `PUT` action is used to update an existing resource. PUT has generally been depreciated in later Rails versions if favor of PATCH due to the semantics of the HTTP verb definitions. In short - use PATCH not PUT.

Change your route definition to:

```
resources :transactions, only: [:show, :create, :update]
```

This will change your routes to:

```
GET /transactions, transactions#index
POST /transactions, transactions#create
PATCH /transactions/:id, transactions#update
```

And your change your test to use the correct HTTP verb:

```
test "should create new transaction" do 
  post :create, { amount: 7000, type: "cars", parent_id: 2 }
  assert_response(:success, message = '{ "status": "ok" }')
end
```

Additionally you should consider a more restful pattern for your additional routes:

```
resources :transactions, only: [:show, :create] do
  collection do
    get :sum # /transactions/sum or the sum of all transactions.
  end
end
```

Its a bit unclear what `/type` does but if it shows transactions per type you might want to use a query param with the index action instead:

```
# GET /transactions?type=car
def index
  @transactions = Transaction.all
  @transactions = @transactions.where(type: params[:type]) if params[:type]
end
```

Additionally you might want follow the rails conventions for parameters:

```
post :create, { transaction: { amount: 7000, type: "cars", parent_id: 2 } }
```

This nesting may seem silly at first but it allows you to use the [Rails form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and strong parameters properly.

Answer (score -1):

In the route, when you say 'PUT  /transaction/:id(.:format) transactions#create', this means that your need send attr id,then in your test need

put :create, { amount: 7000, type: "cars", id: 2 }

or, remove the params id of the route